# how to represent data graphically

Tags: matlab, graph

I have 100 sensors which will be subject to malfunction.100 runs will be made. At each round the mean of all sensor values will be calculated and the deviation from normal will be found.

Deviation can be : 0 1 2 3 4 or 5  from normal.

also at each roun number of live sensors will be calculated.
how to display these 3 data graphically using matlab? do i need to use a 3d plot?

1. correct sensors
2. still functioning (not dead)
3. & all 100 rounds

i.e. i need to see the deviation of mean from normal @ each Round
     at each round some sensors may be dead so i need also to include that the mean is comming from 100-x sensors.

How to display that?

The 3D is too complicated to be read is there another way?

Comment: Is the number of functioning sensors always greater than the number of correct sensors? (i.e. is every correct sensor also a functioning sensor?)

Comment: yes if it is correct it is functioning. well I will edit my question

Comment: Does the order of the runs matter? Or are they effectively repetitions of the same experiment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the identity of the sensors doesn't seem important, (i.e. you are getting the *number* of functioning/correct sensors), I don't think you need a 3d plot. How about this:

```
correct = .... (size: 100-by-1)
functioning = .... (size: 100-by-1)
bar([correct functioning - correct], 'stacked');
legend('Correct', 'Functioning');
xlabel('Run');
ylabel('Sensor Count');
```

This will show 100 bars - one for each run. The top of the bar will be the number of functioning sensors, and there will be a bar beneath it indicating how many of those functioning bars are correct.

I'm assuming that sensors have to be functioning in order to be correct - so `all(functioning > correct) = true`

If you don't like stacked bars (they might be ambiguous) then you could replace the `bar(...)` command with:

```
bar([correct functioning]);
```

---

Looking at the question now, I think a 3-D plot might be best:

```
correct = ... (size: 100-by-1)
functioning = ... (size: 100-by-1)
deviation = ... (size: 100-by-1)
scatter3(correct, functioning, deviation);
xlabel('Correct');
ylabel('Functioning');
zlabel('Deviation');
```

Though maybe it is also meaningful to look at the proportion of functioning sensors that are correct, in which case you could do a 2-D scatter:

```
scatter(correct ./ functioning, deviation);
```

Comment: ah, looks like this isn't the best answer for your updated question, as it doesn't include the deviation.

Comment: I've added some suggestions for including deviation in your visualisation.

Comment: if the identity of the rounds doesn't matter, then `scatter(functioning, deviation)` would work - each scattered point would represent a different round.

Comment: yes as runs increase number of mistakes will increase so i want to know when the system will collaps

Comment: the 3d is not easy to read how to plot it as a bar with two information? @richante